# Converting nvarchar to int, isnumeric returning 0 on a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a temporary table with datatype `NVARCHAR` which I need to migrate to a table with datatype `INTEGER`.

I have two `NVARCHAR` tables which need to be `INTEGER`, one is working and the other is giving an error,

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '9824
>   ' to data type int.

I tried removing that extra space using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` but `ISNUMERIC()` is still giving 0 and the error stays the same.

This is the code resulting in an error,

```
SELECT CAST(table_name AS integer)
FROM OLTP.table
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(Revenue, ' ', '')), Revenue, ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Revenue)), '  ', ' '))
FROM OLTP.ExtractedData
```

Sample Data

```
(No column name)    Revenue (No column name)
0   9824    0
0   5661    0
0   3250    0
0   2959    0
0   2511    0
0   2072    0
0   2056    0
0   1705    0
0   1704    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a linebreak in there, TRIM/RTRIM don't trim those.

```
declare @value nvarchar(10) = '1234
'

select ISNUMERIC(Replace(CHAR(9), '', @value))
select ISNUMERIC(Replace(CHAR(10), '', @value))
select ISNUMERIC(Replace(CHAR(13), '', @value))
select ISNUMERIC(Replace(CHAR(32), '', @value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cast()` use `try_cast()

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(table_name AS integer)
FROM OLTP.table
```

Comment: This produces `NULL`, which happens if the data is not an integer, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT  PARSE(column_name AS int )  from table
```

[image: Tested]

Answer (score 0):

I would check the length. This will give you an idea if how many special characters you are looking for.

```
SELECT LEN(Revenue)
FROM OLTP.ExtractedData
```

Then use `SUBSTRING` and `ASCII` to find out what the character is.

```
SELECT 
  ASCII(SUBSTRING(Revenue, 5, 1))
FROM OLTP.ExtractedData
```